# A bug with using fread (data.table in R) when reading large numbers?

Tags: r, csv, data.table, fread, read.csv

The aim here is to read a csv table, and the file has a direct URL.
I want to use fread (data.table package) because it is faster with read.csv, but I have a little problem.

```
options(scipen=999)

caracteristiques=read.csv(url("https://www.data.gouv.fr/s/resources/base-de-donnees-accidents-corporels-de-la-circulation/20160909-181230/caracteristiques_2015.csv"))
caracteristiques[1,1]
# 201500000001
```

I have to problem to get the [1,1] element.

Now I use fread:

```
library(data.table)   

caracteristiques=data.table(fread("https://www.data.gouv.fr/s/resources/base-de-donnees-accidents-corporels-de-la-circulation/20160909-181230/caracteristiques_2015.csv",
                                      sep=","))
    caracteristiques[1,1]
    #
```

Then we can see a with strange number. I have to specify `options(scipen=0)` to show it `9.955423e-313`I am wondering if I have to specify some options in fread, since they are large numbers in the first column.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`fread` automatically assumed the first column's class to be integer64. From its help file:

> `integer64` = "integer64" (default) reads columns detected as containing integers
>   larger than 2^31 as type bit64::integer64. Alternatively,
>   "double"|"numeric" reads as base::read.csv does; i.e., possibly with
>   loss of precision and if so silently. Or, "character".

The values in the first column are: 201500000001, 201500000002, etc. If you treat them as numbers, they are larger than 2^31 (i.e. 2147483648). Thus `fread` interpreted them as `integer64` values, & caused them to look really strange.

data.table will automatically load the `bit64` package for you in this situation so that the numbers display properly. However, when you don't have `bit64` installed, as you likely don't, it is supposed to warn you and ask you to install it. That lack of warning is bug fix 5 in the development version v1.10.5. From [NEWS](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md) :

> When fread() and print() see integer64 columns are present but package bit64 is not installed, the warning is now displayed as intended. Thanks to a question by Santosh on r-help and forwarded by Bill Dunlap.

So, just `install.packages("bit64")` and you're good.  You don't need to reload the data.  It just affects how those columns are printed.

Alternatively, if you add the argument `integer64 = "numeric"` to your `fread` function, the result will match what you got from `read.csv`. But if it's an ID column, conceptually it should be a character or factor, rather than integer. You can use the argument `colClasses=c("Num_Acc"="character")` for that.

Comment: They don't look strange if the bit64 package is installed.